# Given a quadrilateral, prove it is a square.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

Consider this game.

> You have a perfect ruler and a perfect protractor. You are also able
>   to observe perfectly if two lines are parallel.
>
> Is it possible to prove that a given quadrilateral is a square, using
>   exactly 3 steps?

For example, a proof using 4 steps would be this.

> 1. Observe that opposite sides are parallel (two steps).
> 2. The angle between the diagonals is 90 degrees.
> 3. The angle between any two adjacent sides is 90 degrees.

My gut feeling is that it is not possible to do this in 3 steps and that the minimum would be 4. But how would one prove this?

Comment: @MaxPayne what goes wrong if you measure the two diagonals and then measure the angle between the diagonals?

Comment: @Mathmo123 A quadrilateral can have two diagonals that measure the same and meet at $90$ degrees without it being a square.

Comment: @Darth Geek Are You sure that in Euclidean geometry you can construct a parallelogram whith equal diagonals meeting at $90$ degrees that is not a square. I would be surprised.

Comment: @marwalix Take a square and slide one of its diagonals a bit, keeping them perpendicular

Comment: @Trogdor what defines a step? Right now your step 3. implies step 1. so you can just remove 1.

Comment: @Eugen Covaci A parallelogram has its diagonals meeting at their midpoint. Read my comment carefully. The quadrilateral needs to be a parallelogram. This is the first step.

Comment: @marwalix Darth didn't say "*parallelogram*".

Comment: Step 1 as described by @Trogdor is about a parallelogram

Comment: This isn't rigorous, so this isn't an answer: if one goes by the notion of a square as "a *parallelogram* that is both a *rectangle* and a *rhombus*", then going by my understanding of your notion of a "step", you can't do it in less than four steps: two steps to check if it's a parallelogram, one step to check if it's a rectangle, and one step to check if it's a rhombus.

Comment: @marwalix Darth's reply you commented on wasn't referring to OP's step 1, but rather to Mathmo123's comment, which didn't involve any parallelograms.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I was talking about quadrilarerals in general. Measuring the two diagonals and the angle between them is three steps, but that's not enough to make sure it's a square. If you also make sure that the opposite sides are parallel then you need five steps, which would be a worse solution that OP's.

Comment: @Trogdor It looks to me that in one step you can do (exactly) one of this three options: Check if two lines are parallel, measure the angle between to lines, measure the length of one line. Is that your definition of step?

Comment: @Trogdor `using exactly 3 steps` Since the question has been just bumped up to the main page, here is one more request to clarify what a "*step*" is. `You have a perfect ruler and a perfect protractor` Does a "*perfect measurement*" using either of those count as a "*step*", for example does establishing that two segments are equal count as a step or two steps? How about relations more complex than just equality e.g. is verifying that $\angle A + \angle C = \angle B + \angle D$ one step, or more than one (how many)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible.

A quadrilateral has 4 degrees of freedom, to similarity: place the polygon so it has two of its vertices at $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$.  Then the other two points are free to be (almost) anywhere.  In order to find one of these points we must make two measurements, and the other is completely independent, so there is no measurement that can be used to constrain both.

Comment: I can do it in four though: check that angles $ABC$ and $BAD$ are right, and $ABD$ and $BAC$ are $45^\circ$ -- and that all have the appropriate handedness.

Answer (score 0):

If you can construct lines and verify angels being 90 degrees this is enough. If a quadrilateral has 90 degree angle corners and the diagonal meets in 90 degree angle then it's a square.

First if it's corners are 90 degrees then it's by definition a rectangle. To see that the angle between the diagonals seals the deal you observe that the triangles formed by the diagonals must be isoscele with all having the same length of the sides with same length (because they share these sides with it's neighbor). So the angle between the equal sides is given by trigonometry of the length of this side and the opposite side of the rectangle. If and only if those are equal the angles are equal and they always sum up to 360 (so they must be 90 if and only if they're equal).

Another method is to compare the length of the sides and diagonals (only needing compass). A quadrilateral is a square if and only if the sides are equal and the diagonals are equal. By definition you have a rhombus if and only if the sides are equal. The rest is seen because you will use this to form congruent triangles (which must have the same angles) so the corners of the rhombus must have the same angles and they sum up to 360 degrees (reversely if it's a square you form equal triangles with the diagonals because two sides are the same and the angle between them are the same, that will make the diagonals the same).

If you by "step" mean to measure a length or angle then you will need at least four steps (I think, well almost at least). According to this definition your solution may use more steps as checking that two lines are parallell is done with two measurements (my first solution can be done in four such steps as you only have to measure three corners and one angle between the diagonals). Sloppliy speaking this is because a quadrilateral to be congruent with another five quantities of it need to match and for them to be similar four has to match (or five have to be "proportional"). And a derived quantity (that) depends continuously is just a matter of degrees of freedom.

Comment: The aim is to verify it in fewer than $4$ steps.

Comment: Define "step". Given any number and solution I think I can define "step" to make that solution that number of steps.

Answer (score 0):

Three Steps Solution:
1-see if any pair of adjacent sides are equal.
2-see if any pair of adjacent angles are right angles. 
3-see if both the diagonals are equal

Comment: That looks like $6$ measurements.

Answer (score -1):

Three steps :

1- the diagonals meet at their midpoint (or is it two steps one for each diagonal) : this ensures we have a parallelogram

2- the diagonals are of equal length

3- the diagonal meet at $90$ degrees.

Comment: That looks like $5$ measurements.